# How to deal with Nominal categorical with label encoding?

Tags: machine-learning, python, categorical-data, data-transformation, categorical-encoding

So if my dataset looks like this:

```
  names life_style instrument  times
0   sid   creative      piano    1.5
1  aadi   artistic     guitar    1.4
2  aman  traveller       drum    1.1
3   sid   artistic     guitar    1.5
4  aadi   creative       drum    1.4
```

Now i want to deal with those Nominal categorical variables , Easy and go to approach is use Label encoding , But suppose if i am using sklearn label encoder then:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
big_data = dataset_pd.apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
```

which will output:

```
   names  life_style  instrument  times
0      2           1           2      2
1      0           0           1      1
2      1           2           0      0
3      2           0           1      2
4      0           1           0      1
```

Now it is converting each column but each column have same  numeric values range from 0 to 5. The instrument variable is now similar to 'names' variable since both will have similar data points, which is certainly not a right approach. I have few questions :

- How should i treat those values without loosing information ? better
  approach for this type of data points ?
- I am thinking to use random forest for this type of data , Any
  suggestion on model also will be helpful for me.
- If some variable are appearing only once in huge dataset should i
  remove those variables?

Comment: Usually one would do `OneHotEncoding` to escape this problem.

Answer (score 1):

How to encode a nominal categorical variable? In part that will depend on which kind of model/algorithm you will use later, but the standard advice can be found here [Where to find a guide to encoding categorical features?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/225395/where-to-find-a-guide-to-encoding-categorical-features).  If you have a categorical variable with many levels, see here [Principled way of collapsing categorical variables with many levels?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146907/principled-way-of-collapsing-categorical-variables-with-many-levels).

If you are using a random forest, it might well be that the program will take care of the encoding, or have special requirements as to how you give it the variables.  More ideas here:  [Random Forest Regression with sparse data in Python](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/390671/random-forest-regression-with-sparse-data-in-python/430127#430127)

If some level occurs only once in the dataset, it might be a good idea to use regularization. Maybe that level occurs later in production while using the model!